# Does Propanone trimerise to give 2,6-dimethylhepta-2,5-dien-4-one?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

Does propanone trimerise to give 2,6-dimethylhepta-2,5-dien-4-one?

How and under what conditions?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aldol_condensation

Comment: That compound is more commonly called [phorone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phorone) and it is made by an aldol condensation. However, the cyclic isomer is a little more common: [isophorone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isophorone).

Answer (score 4):

As [the comment](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/66715/does-propanone-trimerise-to-give-2-6-dimethyl-2-5-heptadiene-4-one#comment115229_66715) pointed out, this is an [aldol condensation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aldol_condensation).

I shall demonstrated the acid-catalyzed version.

## Tautomer

[image: tautomer of propanone with propen-2-ol]

Propanone exists in [tautomer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautomer) with propen-2-ol. This is an example of [keto-enol tautomerism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keto%E2%80%93enol_tautomerism), with "keto" referring to the **keto**ne which is propanone, and "enol" referring to prop**en**-2-**ol**.

## Dimer

[image: Mechanism of formation of dimer of propanone]

One molecule of propanone $(1)$ is converted to its tautomer, propen-2-ol $(2\mathrm a)$, with the help of hydrogen ions.

Another molecule of propanone $(1)$ is protonated to form a cation $(2\mathrm b)$.

The central carbon of the protonated propanone is an electrophile, so it attacks the double-bond in the propen-2-ol. A carbon-carbon bond is formed $(3)$.

After deprotonation, the intermediate 4-hydroxy-4-methylpentan-2-one is formed $(4)$.

It is converted to its keto-enol tautomer and the tertiary hydroxyl group is protonated $(5)$.

Then, after [dehydration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dehydration_reaction) $(6)$ and deprotonation, our dimer 4-methylpent-3-en-2-one is formed $(7)$.

This is the first aldol condensation step.

## Trimer

[image: Mechanism of formation of trimer of propnanone]

The mechanism of the formation of the trimer is akin to that of the dimer just above.

Similarly, one molecule of propanone $(1\mathrm a)$ is converted to its tautomer, propen-2-ol $(2\mathrm a)$, with the help of hydrogen ions.

A molecule of the dimer, 4-methylpent-3-en-2-one $(1\mathrm b)$ is protonated to form a cation $(2\mathrm b)$.

The central carbon of the protonated propanone is an electrophile, so it attacks the double-bond in the propen-2-ol. A carbon-carbon bond is formed $(3)$.

After deprotonation, the intermediate 6-hydroxy-2-methylhept-2-en-4-one is formed $(4)$.

It is converted to its keto-enol tautomer and the tertiary hydroxyl group is protonated $(5)$.

Then, after [dehydration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dehydration_reaction) $(6)$ and deprotonation, our trimer 2,6-dimethylhepta-2,5-dien-4-one is formed $(7)$.

This is the second aldol condensation step.